# Override IGNORED_EXCEPTIONS in wedriverwait wait.py

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

Is it possible to globally override the IGNORED_EXCEPTIONS for WebDriverWait?

rather than having

```py
return WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10, ignored_exceptions(StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchFrameException),
                              poll_frequency=1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ID')))
```

i would prefer not to explicitly put these exceptions in every element, i would rather just override the defaults globally if possible

so it should read

```py
return WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ID')))
```

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py#L26C60-L26C85
You can see here on line 26 by default it has NoSuchElementException, can we change this default some how?

I have tried to set it in **init**.py using

```py
import selenium
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException

selenium.webdriver.support.wait.IGNORED_EXCEPTIONS = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
```

but this seem to have no effect

any help is always highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for what i was trying to achieve

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchFrameException, StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import wait

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def set_expected_conditions():
    wait.IGNORED_EXCEPTIONS = (NoSuchElementException, NoSuchFrameException, StaleElementReferenceException)
```

If you create a autouse fixture, this will set the ignored_exceptions for each test

This worked for my framework

i set this in my *webdriver.py*